# Nodejs Typescript type only package is not exporting all types properly

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

The package I'm building (https://github.com/plastikfan/xiberia/tree/develop) is a type only package (I'm not using DefinitelyTyped and this question is not about DT).

The package essentially is just a single file (index.ts) which contains various exported types such as:

```
export interface IYargsFailHandler {
  (msg: string, err: Error, inst: yargs.Argv, command: any): yargs.Argv;
}
```

The problem is, when I use this in a client app, most of the types are missing and the only type that appears by intellisense is:

```
export const CoercivePrimitiveStrArray = ['boolean', 'number', 'symbol'];
```

All the other types are missing.

When I look at the corresponding index.js file, all it contains is:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.CoercivePrimitiveStrArray = ['boolean', 'number', 'symbol'];
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

The generated index.d.ts looks correct and contains all the types, (well there is one very weird definition that I can't account for at the end of the file):

```
export {};
```

My typescript config file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "diagnostics": true,
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es2015",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node", "yargs"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "./index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

So why are most of the types missing and how do I correct it, thanks.

**EDIT:** OOPS, I just made a really silly mistake. The types should not be in the resultant .js file. The only valid js is indeed the CoercivePrimitiveStrArrayCoercivePrimitiveStrArray which is being exported.

But that doesnt explain why the types that are being exported are not shown by intellisense on the clienbt side.

So on the client, this is what I have:

in a client file:

```
import * as xiberia from 'xiberia';
```

When I type, "xiberia.", I would expect to see all the types being exported, but I don't see any.

I read up on the triple slash directive and it appears they are not appropriate for this situation.

So what other config setting do i need for te intellisense to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by simplifying the package as much as possible. Previously, I was building artefacts into the 'dist' folder, a pattern which is widely used. I have removed this (this is a simple single file package, so using a dist folder is overkill) and simply build out the resultant index.d.ts, index.js and the .map files into the root directory. This also required explicity specifiying these files in the 'files' property in package.json (this ensures that these files are included in the resultant package tarball built when performing npm pack via the publish mechanism).

I don't understand why now intellisense is working as a result of these actions; perhaps somebody who knows better can comment.

Comment: I've just discovered, intellisense not working again. Visual studio code, is just very flaky when it comes to intellisense, contrary to all the wild claims about this functionality that drew me into typscript in the first place. Don't believe the hype I guess.